# It is not possible to run Xcode from terminal

Tags: xcode, terminal

On typing:

```
$xed .
```

The following error is shown:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
MacBook-Pro-de-XXXXXX:iOSApp uuuuuuu$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

After installing Xcode type on terminal:

```sh
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: What is your answer answering?